# Countdown for Zxing barcode library

Tags: android, google-glass, zxing, barcode-scanner

I start the scan in my app with intents like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
intent.setPackage("com.google.zxing.client.android");
```

It works well, but if the scanning can't find any match with the image, how can I add a countdown to finish the scanning?

Answer (score 0):

There would be no way for your app to control other apps, unless the target app did some set up and listen for your control, which in this case of `com.google.zxing.client.android` seems no.

https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android/AndroidManifest.xml
https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/Intents.java